# Redimensionar automáticamente

Tags: css, html-select

Estoy haciendo tres etiquetas que quiero que se extiendan a lo ancho de la pantalla siempre sin importar el tamaño de la ventana. Que función de css debo de usar?

Comment: Ocupamos ver tu código HTML y css para saber que responde

Answer (score 0):

usar la unidad relativa "%",este lo que hace es que la etiqueta se adapte o redimensione a cualquier cambio de tamanio de pantalla mantienendo su valor pero relacionado al tamaño de la ventana
una guia respecto a tu caso "width:100%":
lo que hara esto es que ocupara el ancho de toda la pantalla el cual al modificar el tamaño de la ventana del navegador seguira ocupando siempre todo el ancho

```
div{
width:100%;
}

<div>Texto</div>
```

Comment: Por favor, tened en cuenta que no todo el mundo tiene por qué tener las mismas creencias que nosotros. StackOverflow es un lugar para programadores, sean de donde sean y crean en lo que crean. Dejemos a un lado la política y la religión para centrarnos en lo que nos une a todos, el código!